# Размер спрайта изменяется сам по себе после запуска сцены

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: До запуска сцены]

[image: Сразу после запуска сцены]

Почему так и как сделать чтобы размеры не изменялись. В скриптах размеры не меняю. Это делает сам unity. На всём проекте и так один скрипт. Его отключение ничего не дает.

---

Маштабировал через редактор. В коде над этой картиной вообще никаких операций не делал.

Comment: Первый скрин до запуска сцены, второй после запуска.

Comment: Добавьте скриншот с настройками объекта-канваса

Comment: а тут не может быть проблемы со слайдером?

Comment: Написано, что некоторыми свойствами, а именно привязкой, управляет слайдер. И именно привязка и меняется. Так что надо еще слайдер посмотреть

Comment: можно увидеть код? Возможно он подбирает под ваше расширение экрана и по этому может масштабировать.
Вообще это настраивается опцией Pixels per Unit в импорте картинки и в свойствах Canvas.
«В скриптах размеры не меняю. Это делает сам unity»
Если вы сделали размер через код, то тогда юнити запомнил самый первый размер и не меняет его, это уже нужно менять его в самом редакторе Юнити .
Масштаб делали через код или через редактор?

Comment: Я понял из-за чего это происходит. А именно из-за того что изменение параметров Anchors в Rect Transform недоступно. И при запуске он просто сбрасывает то, что поставил я. Как можно открыть это параметры для изменения?